# Where could I find a constructed phylogenetic tree of all metazoa?

Tags: phylogeny

I apologise for this basic question - I am not a phylogenist or even a geneticist, so this is well outside of my knowledge base.

Is there a resource somewhere where I can download a full (synthetic), pre-constructed phylogenetic tree of all metzoa in Newick format? Does this even exist? Most papers that I've found are hyperspecific, focussing on one genus.